# Utf8 string braking one the way to web service function

Tags: web-services, http, unicode, utf

When passing utf8 data to a web service, the data breaks, and it gets to the function with weird symbols after every chunk of text, always in the same location.
This problem does not happen always.
When adding a character that changes the length of the string -the problem disappears.

This problem happens only when sending utf8 characters. When sending English letters, the problem does not happen

example:
this is the string I send (as regular string, not as XML)

```
     string string_to_send="<API><METADATA id="METADATA"><SITE>sapir</SITE> 
       <SESSION_ID>52CA5BF6-472B</SESSION_ID><READER_ID></READER_ID> 
       <LANG_ID>HEB</LANG_ID> <LANG_UI_ID>HEB</LANG_UI_ID><ITEM> 
       <ITEM_ID>1234</ITEM_ID><update><FIELD lif ="SH2" collector_lif="0"  
        collector_val="0"  old_val="N" new_val="N"/><FIELD lif="TA" collector_lif="0"  
        collector_val="0"  old_val=""  
new_val="טטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטט 
טטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטט 
       טטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטטט"/>
        </update></ITEM><IDEASTATE></IDEASTATE></METADATA></API>";
```

This is how I send the data to the function in the web service:

```
 ideaCatApi.idea_edit_item(string_to_send);
```

I have service reference to the web service:
this is the configuration in the web config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="idea_api_cat"  />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint 
       address="http://my_ip/ws/services/idea_api_cat_service"
       binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="idea_api_cat"
       contract="API_cat_idea.idea_api_cat_service" 
       name="idea_api_cat_service" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I run this code from my local machine - Windows 10
to the server - Windows Server 2012 R2

I tried checking if the web service function brakes the text, but its developer said he gets it with the weird symbols

I expect the string to either always brake if there is an encoding problem,
I want to get to a state that the string will get to the web service function with no weird symbols

1. Am I missing headers?
2. I tried encoding the c# string but it did not help
3. Any other idea what can cause the problem?

I tried adding content-type header, but it did not help. So now my code looks like this:

```
using (new OperationContextScope(ideaCatApi.InnerChannel))
                {
                    HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
                    requestMessage.Headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = requestMessage;
                    xmlString = ideaCatApi.idea_edit_item(sb.ToString());
                    response = parseResult(xmlString);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is unanswerable. Show an example string, show the way it arrives on the server, mention your server software and show how exactly you send the string in a request, including relevant headers.

Comment: You're probably missing a content-type header. Show the code that actually sends the string.

Comment: ideaCatApi.idea_edit_item(string_to_send);

Comment: this is the line before:        idea_api_cat_serviceClient ideaCatApi = new idea_api_cat_serviceClient();

Comment: I edited the question and added the code with the content type header. thanks

Comment: What does `ideaCatApi.idea_edit_item()` look like?

Comment: this is the service of a third party so I don't know how it looks. their developer said he gets the parameter we sent with the weird characters.

Comment: You're the one executing the code in `ideaCatApi.idea_edit_item()`. In order to troubleshoot this issue, you must know what this code does. If it issues an `HttpWebRequest`, for example, then the call to OperationContext.Current makes no difference.

Comment: I call it using service reference. soap client

Comment: can someone give me a clue? what can make a string break depends on its length?